# Enable Field Service bundling features in Developer Edition org

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice, fsl

I am attempting to try out the bundling features available in Field Service Lightning. As part of this, I am following the steps outlined in the below support documentation.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fs_set_up_bundling_permissions.htm&type=5

The following necessary permissions are required, but they are not available in the Field Service Settings > Getting Started > Permission Sets menu (see screenshot below).

1. Field Service Bundle for Dispatcher
2. Field Service Integration

How can I get these permission sets added?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: From the linked doc: _NOTE If the Field Service Integration card doesn’t appear, contact Salesforce Customer Support_ Presumably, same approach would work for `Field Service Bundle for Dispatcher`

Comment: Thanks, @identigral

This is on a Dev Edition org, is there any way to get SF support for that

Comment: Officially - no but sometimes they'll help you: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390297&type=1.

Comment: What does your Scratch Org Definition File look like? You should have enabled FSL as an org feature.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is not a Scratch Org, just a Dev Edition org. Would setting up a scratch org allow me to get access to these bundling features?

After seeing your comment, I found the following resource which seems to indicate that I could setup FSL with a scratch org feature, but it does not have any option which clearly indicates that I could get the bundling features.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You can set up with a normal developer edition org by checking the following checkbox ***BEFORE*** installing the FSL managed package.

[image: Box that needs to be checked]

Of course, you need to take all of the other steps needed to setup FSL as well (see below link). The image below shows what step you have to check this box.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fs_set_up.htm&type=5

[image: Step in overall FSL setup process]